# C++ Passing class instance to dlsym() shared library pointer

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, shared

I am trying to implement a program where I am in need to pass a class instance from my main program, to my shared library functions, dynamically opened with dlsym().

I load my lib as follows :

```
IGraphLib*  LibLoader::load(const std::string& file)
{
  this->_dlHandle = dlopen(file.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
  if (this->_dlHandle == NULL)
    {
      std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
      return NULL;
    }
  IGraphLib*    (*loadFunc)();

  loadFunc = reinterpret_cast<IGraphLib* (*)()>(dlsym(this->_dlHandle, "load_lib"));
  if (loadFunc == NULL)
    {
      std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
      return NULL;
    }
  IGraphLib*    inst = loadFunc();

  return inst;
}
```

Then, in my main program, I call the function 'test', member function of the instance of the class in the library I just loaded.

```
Nibbler*        game = NULL;

game = new Nibbler(...)
lib = loader->load(av[3]);
lib->test(game);
```

The test function inside the shared library :

```
void    NibblerSDL::test(Nibbler* game) const
{
  std::cout << game->getWidth() << std::endl;
}
```

And finally the valgrind error, which says that the client is switching stack, so I guess that the problem would come from here, I did some research and I tried to compile with the -rdynamic flag, but it didn't changed anything :

```
==5954== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x7fefff4c8 --> 0x4ea670a35219e347
==5954==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=5667340993508798079 or greater
==5954== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5954==    at 0x40172EC: __longjmp (in /lib64/ld-2.18.so)
==5954== 
==5954== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==5954==    at 0x7C9670A35219E1A7: ???
==5954==  Address 0x7c9670a35219e1a7 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5954== 
==5954== Can't extend stack to 0x4ea670a35219d400 during signal delivery for thread 1:
==5954==   no stack segment
==5954== 
==5954== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5954==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4EA670A35219D400
==5954==    at 0x7C9670A35219E1A7: ???
==5954==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==5954==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==5954==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==5954==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==5954==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==5954== Invalid write of size 8
==5954==    at 0x4A22700: _vgnU_freeres (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so)
==5954==  Address 0x4ea670a35219e2bf is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5954== 
==5954== 
==5954== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5954==  General Protection Fault
==5954==    at 0x4A22700: _vgnU_freeres (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so)
==5954==
```

The load_lib function of the library :

```
extern "C" IGraphLib*   load_lib()
{
  return new NibblerSDL();
}
```

Comment: Did that happen in `load_lib` or in `test`? Did you try increasing the stack size like it says? Did you load the core file and look at the stack trace?

Comment: You should show us the code of "load_lib()" from the library.

Comment: I added the load_lib function in my question. The segfault happens in the test function, and using --max-stackframe since to suppress the segfault but ends in an infinite loop.